# Regex test in scjp test

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to solve an scjp test about regex.

here is a code...

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        boolean b = false;
        while (b = m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
java TestRegex "\d*" ab34ef
```

the answer for this test is `01234456`. I understood everything except the last output(6). Since the last index in "ab34ef" is 5, how is it possible to be printed 6 ?

Any help ....

Comment: ...would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 5):

`\d*` means "zero or more digits," which can actually match nothing.  The 6 is a match against the empty string after the last character in the string.

Comment: ok..thanks..is this empty string regex specific, or it is inherent to all strings?

Comment: @tural I don't really know what you mean .. it has to do with the regex